# What is ARC Welder in Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

- can someone elaborate how to use arc welder?
- what is arc welder used for and how do I test my app with it?

Comment: If you do not intend to distribute your app on chrome OS then you should really ignore the ability to use the ARC. It is not a good testing environment for Android apps(yet).

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC Welder is a chrome app that allows you to package an android app as a chrome app. This means that your android app will be able to be executed and distributed for Chrome OS. For more information on ARC visit: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

Note: you can create and run arc apps on nearly anything but for now the apps can only be downloaded through the web store on chrome OS devices.

Step 1: download [ARC Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn).

Step 2: Choose Working directory.(this is where the ARC apps will be sent to)

Step 3: add apk.

Step 4 choose [orientation/form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468880/how-to-custom-the-screen-size-of-arc-welder/29473784#29473784)

Step 5 optional: Add metadata

Step 6: Launch app by selecting the launch button.

Answer (score 0):

For using ARC Welder, you need to download the [Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn), and also the APK for testing your app. You can read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc).

It will run your app, as bluestacks or other emulator. It's more for debug.

Please keep in mind that this is a Developer Preview, so it may not be perfect.