# How to customize the screen size of ARC-Welder?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I would like to change the screen size of the ARC-Welder chrome-extention to a 7inch screen - displayed on my pc - to test an app on different screen sizes.

Can this be done using for example the meta-data input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to a question that I asked recently but I think shares the same answer. It seems that there are few choices when it comes to form factor, and based on the answer to my question I think that you can only use the three form factor presets for now.

(from @Elijah Taylor)

The size of the window is not configurable per activity*, but the orientation is. The two options in ARC Welder that control the window are:

- Orientation: This is either landscape or portrait, which will be the default orientation for your app. However, if you set a screenOrientation on your Android activity, this can override the orientation per activity, with the window rotating to compensate. There is a performance cost to rotating this way because the plugin will be rotated via CSS.
- ***Form Factor: This is one of phone, tablet, or maximized. This controls the overall size of your app globally.***
- but for Chrome 42 and up you can use the metadata {"resize": "reconfigure"} to allow arbitrary user resizing. Your app must be able to relayout with a variety of aspect ratios and resolutions in this mode.

My question at:[Android ARC app for chrome, set size of windows for different Activities/Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421771/android-arc-app-for-chrome-set-size-of-windows-for-different-activities-layouts)

Answer (score 1):

You can Use this MetaData :

```
{
    "resize":"reconfigure"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just thought i'd mention that there is also `"formFactor": "fullscreen"` if want to test full screen it also works with `"resize":"reconfigure"`